# jquery get click button value send it to listbox

Tags: jquery

I need to have click buttons values and send it to listbox.Below is my code and i comment in the middle of the code that i need to get the values of the buttons which is clicked and send it to a listbox

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>

        $(function () {
            var count = 0;
            $('input[type=button]').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                count += 1;
                if (count % 2 === 0) {
                    $(this).css('background-color', '#6FA478');
                   //I have to get here the value of every click button and send it to listbox 

                }
                else {
                    $(this).css('background-color', '');
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This, where you have comment

```
var value = $(this).val();
$("[id$=ListBox2]").append('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>');
```

So code should be like

```
$(function () {
    var count = 0;
    $('input[type=button]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        count += 1;
        if (count % 2 === 0) {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#6FA478');
            //I have to get here the value of every click button and send it to listbox 
            var value = $(this).val();
            $("[id$=ListBox2]").append('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>');
        }
        else {
            $(this).css('background-color', '');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I can not see the values in the listbox but more i click the buttons scroll bar of the listbox emerges,like invisible values stay there

Answer (score 0):

try this to get current clicked button value

```
$(this).val();
```

or

```
 this.value
```